# How to recover the tablespace from backup pending state in DB2

Tags: db2, backup, db2-luw

Should I go with this below command to recover the tablespace in DEV environment, or is there a better solution?

`db2 "backup database DEV tablespace (xyz) online to /dev/null"`

Comment: "Better" according to what critera? What's wrong with taking a backup?

Comment: Actually when I was trying to drop the table its taking too much time..I checkd with the tablsepace its in backup pending state..So,I thought It will be the reason for taking so much time when I ran the drop table statement.

Answer (score 0):

If a table space is backup pending, it's usually due to some event that requires a new backup point, such as after a LOAD .. COPY NO.  In such a situation it is best advised that you take a new backup to an actual location to save the image for future recoveries through this point in time.

If not, you could be exposed to data loss until a new backup including this table space is completed.

Thanks.